# move the order of windows in Titanium.UI.iOS.NavigationWindow

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

i have created a navigation window  - Titanium.UI.iOS.NavigationWindow

i have added three windows

i have open all three windows

now how do i make window3 come first with out closing window1 and window 2

```
var ani =false;
var winRoot = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
  backgroundColor: 'red',
  title: 'Red Window'
});


var win = Titanium.UI.iOS.createNavigationWindow({
  window: winRoot
});

var button = Titanium.UI.createButton({
    title: 'Open Blue Window'
});
button.addEventListener('click', function(){
    win.openWindow(win1, {animated:ani});
});

winRoot.add(button);





var win1 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
  backgroundColor: 'blue',
  title: 'Blue Window'
});

var button1 = Titanium.UI.createButton({
    title: 'Open Green Window'
});
button1.addEventListener('click', function(){
    win.openWindow(win2, {animated:ani});
});

win1.add(button1);






var win2 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
  backgroundColor: 'green',
  title: 'green Window'
});

var button2 = Titanium.UI.createButton({
    title: 'Open Yellow Window'
});
button2.addEventListener('click', function(){
    win.openWindow(win3, {animated:ani});
});

win2.add(button2);





var win3 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
  backgroundColor: 'yellow',
  title: 'yellow Window'
});



var button3 = Titanium.UI.createButton({
    title: 'Open Blue Window'
});
button3.addEventListener('click', function(){
    win.openWindow(win1, {animated:ani});
});

win3.add(button3);


win.open();
```

in button3 i cannot go back to blue window without closing the yellow and green window

Answer (score 1):

You can't open in NavigationWindow the same window twice. If you want to bring it to front you have to close it and than open again:

Below is your code modified. I created one event listener which closes and opens given window based on buttons custom property `target`:

```
var windows = {};

function openWindow() {
    win.closeWindow( windows[this.target] );    
    win.openWindow( windows[this.target] );
}

windows.red = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
  backgroundColor: 'red',
  title: 'Red Window'
});

var win = Titanium.UI.iOS.createNavigationWindow({
    window: windows.red
});

var button = Titanium.UI.createButton({
    title: 'Open Blue Window',
    target: 'blue'
});
button.addEventListener('click', openWindow);
windows.red.add(button);


windows.blue = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
  backgroundColor: 'blue',
  title: 'Blue Window'
});

var button1 = Titanium.UI.createButton({
    title: 'Open Green Window',
    target: 'green'
});
button1.addEventListener('click', openWindow);
windows.blue.add(button1);


windows.green = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
  backgroundColor: 'green',
  title: 'green Window'
});

var button2 = Titanium.UI.createButton({
    title: 'Open Yellow Window',
    target: 'yellow'
});
button2.addEventListener('click', openWindow);
windows.green.add(button2);


windows.yellow = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
  backgroundColor: 'yellow',
  title: 'yellow Window'
});

var button3 = Titanium.UI.createButton({
    title: 'Open Blue Window',
    target: 'blue',
});
button3.addEventListener('click', openWindow);
windows.yellow.add(button3);


win.open();
```

The other approach would be creating new window with same parameters:

```
var params = {
    red: {
        window: {
            backgroundColor: 'red',
            title: 'Red Window',
        },
        button: {
            title: 'Open Blue Window',
            target: 'blue'
        }
    },
    blue: {
        window: {
            backgroundColor: 'blue',
            title: 'Blue Window',
        },
        button: {
            title: 'Open Green Window',
            target: 'green'
        }
    },
    green: {
        window: {
            backgroundColor: 'green',
            title: 'Green Window',
        },
        button: {
            title: 'Open Yellow Window',
            target: 'yellow'
        }
    },
    yellow: {
        window: {
            backgroundColor: 'yellow',
            title: 'Yellow Window',
        },
        button: {
            title: 'Open Red Window',
            target: 'red'
        }
    }
};

function createWindow(color) {
    var win = Titanium.UI.createWindow(params[color].window);
    var button = Titanium.UI.createButton(params[color].button);
    win.add(button);
    button.addEventListener('click', function() {
        navwin.openWindow( createWindow( this.target ) );
    });
    return win;
}

var navwin = Titanium.UI.iOS.createNavigationWindow({
    window: createWindow('red')
});

navwin.open();
```

Try both examples and check which behaviour suits you better.

Comment: Ok, now your question is much more clear. I created two working examples, see edits above.